# Quando utilizar o constructor quando utilizar o load

Tags: c#, winforms, construtor, load

Galera boa noite, como vai?
Estou com uma duvida, quando se deve utilizar o constructor e quando se deve utlizar o load de um form para chamar algum metodo ou etc.

Exemplo:

```
 public partial class Manutenção_cliente : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
{
    consulta_bd consulta_bd = new consulta_bd();
    cadastro_bd cadastro_bd = new cadastro_bd();
    excluir_bd excluir_bd = new excluir_bd();
    controles_text control_text = new controles_text();
    DataTable cobranca = new DataTable();
    DataTable entrega = new DataTable();

    public int id_cliente, editar, chek_excluir, chek_new_cli, contador, id_end_cobranca, id_end_entrega;

    public Manutenção_cliente(int id)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        id_cliente = id;
        populargrid_cobranca(id);
        dateTimePicker1.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void lod ()
    {
        textBox13.ReadOnly = true;

        if (id_cliente != 0)
        {
            textBox13.Text = Convert.ToString(id_cliente);
            Dictionary<string, string> preenche_cliente = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            preenche_cliente = consulta_bd.preenche_cliente(id_cliente);

            textBox1.Text = preenche_cliente["razao_social"];
            textBox2.Text = preenche_cliente["nome_fantasia"];
            comboBox1.Text = preenche_cliente["tipo_doc"];
            textBox3.Text = preenche_cliente["n_doc"];
            textBox4.Text = preenche_cliente["ie"];
            textBox5.Text = preenche_cliente["im"];
            textBox6.Text = preenche_cliente["endereco"];
            textBox7.Text = preenche_cliente["numero"];
            textBox8.Text = preenche_cliente["cep"];
            textBox9.Text = preenche_cliente["bairro"];
            textBox10.Text = preenche_cliente["cidade"];
            textBox11.Text = preenche_cliente["estado"];
            textBox12.Text = preenche_cliente["pais"];
            textBox14.Text = preenche_cliente["requisitos"];
            textBox16.Text = preenche_cliente["email"];
            textBox15.Text = preenche_cliente["telefone"];

            int bloq = Convert.ToInt16(preenche_cliente["bloqueado"]);
            if (bloq == 0)
            {
                checkBox1.Checked = false;
            }
            else
            {
                checkBox1.Checked = true;
            }

            foreach (Control ctl in xtraTabPage1.Controls)
            {
                if (ctl is TextEdit)
                {
                    ((TextEdit)(ctl)).ReadOnly = true;
                }

                if (ctl is TextBox)
                {
                    ((TextBox)(ctl)).ReadOnly = true;
                }
            }

            foreach (Control ctl in xtraTabPage3.Controls)
            {
                if (ctl is TextEdit)
                {
                    ((TextEdit)(ctl)).ReadOnly = true;
                }

                if (ctl is TextBox)
                {
                    ((TextBox)(ctl)).ReadOnly = true;
                }
            }

            control_text.textedit_readonly_true(this.Controls);
        }
        else
        {
            int v = consulta_bd.consulta_id_cliente();
            contador = v + 1;

            textBox13.Text = Convert.ToString(contador);
        }
    }

    private void Manutenção_cliente_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lod();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### A resposta é *depende*. Tudo depende, sempre.

Você que deve saber qual o melhor lugar para colocar o carregamento dos componentes ou seja lá o que pretenda fazer. O que você **precisa** mesmo saber é quando cada um é disparado.

O construtor do form é um construtor normal, logo os métodos (ou instruções nele) serão executados logo que você instanciar um novo form.

Já o evento `Load` só vai ser disparado quando o form for mostrado pela primeira vez (ao usar o método `Show` ou `ShowDialog`.

Ainda existe o evento `Shown`, este vai ser disparado todas as vezes que o form se tornar visível (ao fazer `form.Show` - depois do `Load` - e `form.Visible = true`). Se você "esconder" o form e torná-lo visível de novo, o evento `Shown` será disparado novamente.

Ex.:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AlgumMetodo();
    }
}
```

Geralmente, para chamar um form, se faz assim

```
 Form1 form = new Form1(); //Chama o construtor e, consequentemente, o InitializeComponent
 form.Show(); //Dispara o Load que, por sua vez, executa AlgumMetodo
 //o Shown será disparado logo após o Load
```

Comment: Ha perfeito amigo, achei que tivesse definiçoes tipo, no constructor e usado para declarar variaveis por exemplo. mas blz, entendi, e vou estudar o caso. Valeu